# How to limit SSH access to specific IPv6 address with iptables?

Tags: iptables, ipv6

I have the following two rules applied for ipv4:

```
-A INPUT -s 5.70.139.172/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

The above works for ipv4.

I have installed the ip6tables package and I've tried to copy these two lines (with the ipv4 address replaced with ipv6) to the default ip6tables config file. However these changes to do not seem to take effect?

Is this because firewalld is used instead perhaps?

```
systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-06-22 16:05:41 UTC; 1h 47min ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
 Main PID: 507 (firewalld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
           └─507 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid

Jun 22 16:49:37 li1663-14.members.linode.com firewalld[507]: ERROR: Failed to load '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0': [Errno 13] Permission denied: ...fg-eth0'
Jun 22 16:49:37 li1663-14.members.linode.com firewalld[507]: ERROR: Calling post func <function ifcfg_set_zone_of_interface at 0x7f353247caa0>(('public', 'eth...fg-eth0'
Jun 22 16:49:51 li1663-14.members.linode.com firewalld[507]: ERROR: Failed to load '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0': [Errno 13] Permission denied: ...fg-eth0'
Jun 22 16:49:51 li1663-14.members.linode.com firewalld[507]: ERROR: Calling post func <function ifcfg_set_zone_of_interface at 0x7f353247caa0>(('public', 'eth...fg-eth0'
Jun 22 16:52:05 li1663-14.members.linode.com firewalld[507]: ERROR: Failed to load '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0': [Errno 13] Permission denied: ...fg-eth0'
Jun 22 16:52:05 li1663-14.members.linode.com firewalld[507]: ERROR: Calling post func <function ifcfg_set_zone_of_interface at 0x7f353247caa0>(('public', 'eth...fg-eth0'
Jun 22 17:46:11 li1663-14.members.linode.com firewalld[507]: ERROR: Failed to load '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0': [Errno 13] Permission denied: ...fg-eth0'
Jun 22 17:46:11 li1663-14.members.linode.com firewalld[507]: ERROR: Calling post func <function ifcfg_set_zone_of_interface at 0x7f353247caa0>(('public', 'eth...fg-eth0'
Jun 22 17:51:58 li1663-14.members.linode.com firewalld[507]: ERROR: Failed to load '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0': [Errno 13] Permission denied: ...fg-eth0'
Jun 22 17:51:58 li1663-14.members.linode.com firewalld[507]: ERROR: Calling post func <function ifcfg_set_zone_of_interface at 0x7f353247caa0>(('public', 'eth...fg-eth0'
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

I'm using centos 7.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the ip6tables package. Iptables is just for ipv4 addresses. You will need to make a new config with ipv6 rules in them.